# Write $(-e)^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ in the form $a+bi$

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that I can write this as
$$(e^{i\pi} e)^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
but I can't seem to figure out how to write it in $a+bi$ form-- I am unsure of how to deal with the $\pi^2$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be $(e^{i\pi} e)^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited it

Comment: Alternatively, it is valid to write $-1$ more generally as $e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$, instead of $e^{i\pi}$. This will lead to the same answer as going back to definition (shown in Nick’s answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(-e)^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\log(-e)}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(log(e)+i(\pi+2\pi k))}=e^{-(\pi+2\pi k)\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{i log(e)\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and we know $log(e)=1$

Using Euler's formula we get
$$e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{2}(1+2 k)}i$$